# Using matplotlib to display a simple plot to no avail

Tags: matplotlib

#the following code runs error free but is not displayed what might be the issue:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squares = [1,4,9,16,25]

plt.plot(squares)

plt.show()
```

Just got started with matplotlib Tried running the simple code, expected the display to show the plot but it just runs without having anything happen, tested several backends like Qt5agg and still nothing

Comment: Based on the documentation, you have to activate in IPython by adding `%matplotlib tk` on the begin of your code (and it requires TkInter).

Comment: I realise you want to display the plot, but just as a check, if you use `plt.savefig("test.png")` instead of `plt.show()`, does it create a file called `test.png` that you can open?

Comment: Could you say what operating system you are using and what Python version? Also, are you running your code from a script, or directly in a `python` or `ipython` terminal, or in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I'm using windows os, and running it in jupyter notebook within vs code, tried running savefig but didn't create file.how do I use %matplotlib tk since it registers as an error. Do I import tkinter?  I've noticed that the issue might also be the kernel but it keeps failing to install. Any further advice is highly welcome(bear with me, I'm a newbie)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was not the code itself but rather in the installation of matplotlib. I believe I might have installed matplotlib that was incompatible with my python version which might have corrupted the python files since even pygame was no longer bringing up the graphical display. I installed an updated version of python, deleted the previous one,also deleted the troublesome matplotlib and pygame and the installed each of them afresh. Thereafter everything was working fine